# How to merge objects in array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays

i have a array like here

```
    let array = [
  {
    yearBirth : 1995,
    name : 'daniel',
  },
  {
    yearBirth : 1995,
    name : 'avi',
  },
  {
    yearBirth : 1993,
    name : 'john',
  },
  {
    yearBirth : 1993,
    name : 'david',
  },
]
```

How do I make it something like that?

```
{yearBirth : [
      {1995 : [{name : 'daniel'},{name : 'avi'}]},
      {1993 : [{name : 'john'},{name : 'david'}]}
    ]}
```

I tried to do it in a few ways I also looked for solutions here I did not find ... I would love a solution, thanks

Comment: we would like to help you if you show us what you've tried!?

Comment: I tried to make a map and the map has to filter and it did not really work for me and I am looking for another solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you'd be filtering (or why the `yearBirth` property is an array instead of an object keyed by the year, each value being an array of the names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to group by `yearBirth` property,
then put it result in property `yearBirth` as an array:

```js
let array = [{
    yearBirth: 1995,
    name: "daniel",
  },
  {
    yearBirth: 1995,
    name: "avi",
  },
  {
    yearBirth: 1993,
    name: "john",
  },
  {
    yearBirth: 1993,
    name: "david",
  },
];
const grouped = array.reduce(function (acc, val) {
    (acc[val.yearBirth] = acc[val.yearBirth] || []).push(val);
    return acc;
}, {});

let output = {
    yearBirth: [grouped]
}
console.log(output);
```

if you don't get the part of grouping there's a utility library called  [`underscorejs`](https://underscorejs.org/) with method [groupBy](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)

```js
const grouped = _.groupBy(array, "yearBirth");
```

Also there are other methods to groupby on an array of objects without third-party library [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: its Work !
Thank you !!
And how do i add reverse() to it?

Comment: I want what is first in the array to be at the end.

Comment: You could call method `reverse()` _but_ what do you want reverse the obj or the array?

Comment: i want reserver() the obj

Comment: Maybe the object couldn't be reversed since its data structre pairs of key and value

Comment: Yes I also can not map it ...